# BitFinex API call returns 400 bad request - "Could not find a key matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY"

Tags: api, authentication, bitfinex

I dont know what I'm doing wrong, but everytime I try send post request "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/balances" or some else I got this answer "Could not find a key matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY".

I was trying some aplication, make-online-request-sites, my own program and code from this page [BitFinex API call returns 400 bad request](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/bitfinex-api-call-returns-400-bad-request).

My api-key looks like dddd where d is digit.

Maybe I dont know how looks like key-api. This should be first column on this site https://www.bitfinex.com/account/api, right? Second is api-secret. Really... I cant understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the API key once, when it's generated.

[image: bitfinex api key]

You have to generate another one.

It's sorta mystifying that they would show the API secret whenever you look at that page, but only show the API key once. I dunno why they did that.